# Gradle refuse to start process command 'cmd'

Tags: testing, gradle, groovy, cmd, allure

I'm encountering issue with a custom gradle task. Seems like gradle refuse to start a command line process.

Here is the custom task:

```
task generateAllure(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/allure/bin"
    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'allure.bat', 'generate', '-c', '../../integration/build/allure-results'
    } else {
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'allure', 'generate', '-c',"$projectDir/integration/build/allure-results"
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test)*.finalizedBy generateAllure
```

With the appropriate dependency:

```
compile group: 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure', name: 'allure-commandline', version: '1.4.18'
```

After using `gradle clean test` execution fails on:

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateAllure'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'cmd''
```

Any thoughts about that? Thanks!

UPD:
This is the stacktrace i'm getting after performing gradle -S clean test:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generateAllure'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'cmd''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:231)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:355)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'cmd'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:67)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "D:\Git\rozetka-test-automation\allure\bin"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try running `gradle -S clean test` and post the full stacktrace in your question.
I would also suggest creating a reproducible github repo

Comment: @Boaz Hello there! May i ask your attention again? I've added the full stacktrace after performing the gradle -S clean test. If you have any thoughts please share them with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now with the stacktrace the problem is pretty much clear.
In the task you defined

```
task generateAllure(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$projectDir/allure/bin"
    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'allure.bat', 'generate', '-c', '../../integration/build/allure-results'
    } else {
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'allure', 'generate', '-c',"$projectDir/integration/build/allure-results"
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test)*.finalizedBy generateAllure
```

You've set the working directory to `"$projectDir/allure/bin"` this value get interpolated into `"D:\Git\rozetka-test-automation\allure\bin"` which apparently doesn't exist on your system

Keep in mind that "doesn't exist" might also mean "doesn't exist **yet**", it depends on what you're doing in the rest of your build.

Under the assumption the `allure\bin` is not created by the build - something is wrong with your path.